# Modeling wordpress taxonmy in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress

I need to access a wordpress database in rails. Yeah, fun times. I've been able to get at the blog content ok, but I need to access the "category" for each blog post. The categories are 2 joins away. The raw sql to get at this content is as follows:

```
select term.name from wp_term_relationships rel
inner join wp_term_taxonomy as tt
on rel.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
inner join wp_terms as term
on term.term_id = tt.term_id
where object_id = 123
and taxonomy = 'category';
```

I already have a WpTerm and WpPost classes. I need to now figure out how to tie these together using AR.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working for me (I'm loading from Wordpress as secondary database, hence the `establish_connection()` calls and overriding `table_name`.

```
class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
   establish_connection "wordpress-#{Rails.env}"
   self.table_name = "wp_terms"

   has_one :term_taxonomy
end


class TermTaxonomy < ActiveRecord::Base
   establish_connection "wordpress-#{Rails.env}"
   self.table_name = "wp_term_taxonomy"

   belongs_to :term
   has_many :term_relationship
end

class TermRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
   establish_connection "wordpress-#{Rails.env}"
   self.table_name = "wp_term_relationships"

   belongs_to :post, :foreign_key => "object_id"
   belongs_to :term_taxonomy
   has_one :term, :through => :term_taxonomy
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   establish_connection "wordpress-#{Rails.env}"
   self.table_name = "wp_posts"

   has_many :term, :through => :term_relationship
   has_many :term_relationship, :foreign_key => "object_id"
   has_one  :postmeta

   # we only care about published posts for notifications
   default_scope where("post_type = 'post' and post_status = 'publish'")
end

class Postmeta < ActiveRecord::Base
   establish_connection "wordpress-#{Rails.env}"
   self.table_name = "wp_postmeta"

   belongs_to :post
end
```

I then wrap up the category in a simple ruby object that makes accessing the data easy:

```
class WPCategory
   attr_accessor :id
   attr_accessor :name
   attr_accessor :description
   attr_accessor :term

   def self.categories()
      categories = Term.all()
      categories = categories.select{|term| term.term_taxonomy.taxonomy == "category"}
      return categories.map{|term| WPCategory.new(term)}
   end

   def self.category(id=nil)
      if id
         term = Term.find(id)
         if term.term_taxonomy.taxonomy == "category"
            return WPCategory.new(term)
         end
      end
      return nil
   end

   def initialize(term)
      @id = term.term_id
      @name = term.name
      @description = term.term_taxonomy.description
      @term = term
   end

   def to_s
      return "Wordpress Category: '#{@name}' (id=#{@id})"
   end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same challenge of mapping a Wordpress datamodel in Activerecord.

Ari Gesher's answer was very helpful but I think the vanilla ruby class WPCategory isn't necessary. Also looking at Wordpress's [ERD](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png): Term has many term taxonomies instead of one. So my Wordpress models look like this (**note that I use Rails 2.3**):

```
class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection Rails.configuration.database_configuration["wordpress_#{Rails.env}"]
  set_table_name 'wp_terms'
  set_primary_key 'term_id'

  has_many :term_taxonomies
end

class TermTaxonomy < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection Rails.configuration.database_configuration["wordpress_#{Rails.env}"]
  set_table_name 'wp_term_taxonomy'
  set_primary_key 'term_taxonomy_id'

  belongs_to :term
  has_many :term_relationships

  named_scope :categories, :conditions => {:taxonomy => 'category'}
end

class TermRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection Rails.configuration.database_configuration["wordpress_#{Rails.env}"]
  set_table_name 'wp_term_relationships'
  set_primary_key 'object_id'

  belongs_to :post, :foreign_key => 'object_id'
  belongs_to :term_taxonomy
  has_one :term, :through => :term_taxonomy
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection Rails.configuration.database_configuration["wordpress_#{Rails.env}"]
  set_table_name 'wp_posts'
  set_primary_key 'ID'

  has_many :term_relationships, :foreign_key => 'object_id'
  has_many :term_taxonomies, :through => :term_relationships

  default_scope :conditions => {:post_type => 'post', :post_status => 'publish'}

  def categories
    term_taxonomies.categories.map(&:term)
  end
end
```

I replaced Ari Gesher's WPCategory by a named_scope in TermTaxonomy and a categories method in Post.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
require 'mysql2'
require 'active_record'
require 'composite_primary_keys'
require 'pry'

spec = {
  adapter:  :mysql2,
  username: :root,
  database: '7fff_com'
}

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(spec)

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'wp_posts'
  self.primary_key = 'ID'
  has_many :post_term_taxonomies, :foreign_key => :object_id
  has_many :term_taxonomies, through: :post_term_taxonomies

  def categories
    term_taxonomies.where(taxonomy: 'category').map { |t| t.term.name }
  end
  def tags
    term_taxonomies.where(taxonomy: 'post_tag').map { |t| t.term.name }
  end
end

class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'wp_terms'
  self.primary_key = 'term_id'
  has_many :post_term_taxonomies, :foreign_key => :term_taxonomy_id
  has_many :posts, through: :post_term_taxonomies
  has_one :term_taxonomy, primary_key: :term_id
end

class PostTermTaxonomy < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'wp_term_relationships'
  self.primary_keys = :object_id, :term_taxonomy_id
  belongs_to :post, foreign_key: :object_id
  belongs_to :term_taxonomy, foreign_key: :term_taxonomy_id
end

class TermTaxonomy < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'wp_term_taxonomy'
  self.primary_key = 'term_taxonomy_id'
  belongs_to :term
end
```

A pry session would look like this:

```
[1] pry(main)> post = Post.find(764)
[2] pry(main)> post.categories
=> ["Technology", "Code"]
[3] pry(main)> post.tags
=> ["boxen"]
```

See http://7fff.com/2015/01/moving-from-wordpress-to-middleman-part-i/